Get the pixel coordinates from a Longitude, Latitude coordinate pair for a GetFeatureInfo request?
Given a GetFeatureInfo Query:
https://path/geoserver/data_store/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&QUERY_LAYERS=workspace_name:layer&LAYERS=workspace_name:layer&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=70&SRS=EPSG:27572&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=597160.0516763324,2377828.814033716,628006.0418877505,2408674.804245134
In above query the X, Y parameters are pixel coordinates that geoserver manage as they are, but I have a pair of Longitude, Latitude coordinates that I want to use within the query for test the output.
How to convert these geographic coordinates in valid pixel coordinates ?
Fake Example :
Lon, lat = (597160.0516763324,2377828.814033716) => expressed in pixel coordinates are X, Y = (5, 45)

Then you want to use the WCS end point, the WMS is just a picture of the data .

Are you using a client side JavaScript library to create this GetFeatureURL?

your example coordinates aren't in Latitude and longitude

This WMS GetFeatureInfo query only interprets pixel coordinates, typically retrieved from an event, such as a click or mouse position.

A GetFeatureInfo request works on the the pixel coordinates of an image that is generated by the WMS as part of a GetMap request.  So you will need to turn your lat long coordinates (or other coordinates that match the SRS/CRS of your request) into a bounding box somehow.  Then if you make the image size a 2 by 2 pixel, and x, y both 1 then you should probably return the information you need.
